# Revert back to Alternating Row Color with DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have set AlternatingRowStyle BackColor through the Visual Studio IDE and my question is, if I modify the BackColor of a cell based on some condition, how do I 'unset' it to the correct row color (i.e. white or the alternating row color) without resorting to modulo of the RowIndex.

I have tried the following with apparent success but I am not 100% if this is the solution:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value);

        if (d > 5)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.ApplyStyle(dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is apparent success? what do you intend to reach exactly?

Comment: Basically if a odd row (say Color.White) is set to red due to the condition, it will be set back to white when it no longer meets the condition. And when a even row (say Color.Yellow) is set to to red due to the condition, it will be set back to yellow when it no longer meets the condition. By apparent success, I mean it seems to be working but I haven't had a chance to test extensively and am trying to work out if there is a better way. I've tried searching but it is tough to phrase

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DataGridViewCellPainting`, edit the `CellStyle` in `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs`

It seems that the `e.CellStyle` do not actually affect `cell.CellStyle`, that means you do not need to reset cell if the condition was not met

Answer (score 0):

since you decide the `backColor` of cells according to their values, I suggest you to use `CellValueChanged` event.

**Example**:

I assume the *odd* rows, to be yellow and the *even* rows to be white by default, in case any cell meets the condition (value > 5) it will be displayed in red.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int col = e.ColumnIndex;
    int row = e.RowIndex;
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[col, row].Value);

    switch (row%2)
    {
        case 0:
           if (d > 5)
               dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
           else
               dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        break;
        case 1:
           if (d > 5)
               dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
           else
               dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        break;
   }
}
```